# VB.NET UserControl exposed as ActiveX control VisibleChanged not called when run in VB6

Tags: vb.net, winforms, com-interop, vb6-migration

I am working on migrating a VB6 UserControl to VB.NET and Windows Forms. Some of the initialization and de-initialization in the VB6 code was done in the UserControl_Show() and UserControl_Hide() handlers; per the suggestion of VB Migration Partner, I handled the VisibleChanged event in the migrated code to call these.

```
<ComVisible(True)>
Public Class MigratedUserControl
    Inherits UserControl

    ' This is never called when used with a VB6 form.
    Private Sub Me_VisibleChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.VisibleChanged
        Debug.Print("Me_VisibleChanged")

        If Me.Visible AndAlso Not mBeenShown Then
            mBeenShown = True
            UserControl_Show()
        ElseIf Not Me.Visible AndAlso mBeenShown Then
            mBeenShown = False
            UserControl_Hide()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The migrated control is exposed as an ActiveX control. When run in the ActiveX Test Container (TstCon32.exe), the VisibleChanged event is called as expected. However, when added to a VB6 form (yes, some of our customers will want to do this) and the form is run in the VB6 IDE, the VisibleChanged handler in the migrated control is not called.

Do I need to do something special in VB6 for this event to be raised?

Comment: I was able to duplicate your issue.  Dropping the control onto the VB6 form did not fire the event.  Minimizing and Maximizing the VB6 app did not fire the event.  The only way I could get the event to fire was to explicitly toggle the `Visible` property of the control.

Comment: WM_SHOWWINDOW is called at different points in the control's life depending on whether it is being run by VB6, the ActiveX Control Test Container or Winforms.